# PHP, MYSQL - how to get rows according date?

Tags: php, mysql, date

In the database column called `date` (tyupe **int(11)**) I have stored the date as integer. Then, I have variables `$day`, `$month`, `$year` and I would need to get all rows for the respective day (which represent variables `$day`, `$month`, `$year`).

How to do that?

I've tried this way:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM persons WHERE DATE_FORMAT( `date` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) =
            '".date("$year-$month-$day")."'")
```

But this unfortunately doesn't works me... Could anyone give me a tip, please, how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` returns a nicely formatted **string**, `DATE()` returns a **date**.

Comment: Store dates as `DATE` and integers as `INT`. The conversions from one to other format and vice versa are going to be cumbersome and slow otherwise.

Comment: .. But it can be done using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function, for example. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime Or use the `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Comment: Say, for example that a row has `date=1`. WHich date is that? `1900-01-01`? `2000-01-01`? `1001-01-01`? `1752-09-14`? Where does your calendar start? How should MySQL know that?

Comment: @biziclop: Yes, but only if the OP is not storing dates but unix timestamps in int columns. We don't know that, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to avoid having to wrap your date column in a function in order to still be able to utilize indexes.

This is the most efficient method for your scenario, provided you have an index set up on the `date` column:

```
$input_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM persons WHERE date = $input_date");
```

---

It would be an even better idea to actually store the `date` column as an actual `DATE` type. That way, you can make all sorts of compelling date comparisons and calculations that you otherwise couldn't with a simple integer-based unix timestamp.